# only can display 1 image. If the user have more that 1 image how to display it

Tags: php, mysql

in my programe, user login and can upload images. user may view all his images and delete it.

The problem is i only can display 1 image. If the user have more that 1 image how to display it.

display.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();
$reg_user = new USER();
$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM bike_tbl WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$userID=$row['userID'];
echo $userID;
if(isset($_POST['btn-update']))
{
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $remarks = $_POST['remarks'];


    if($reg_user->updateBike($status,$remarks,$userID))
    {
        echo "good";


    }
    else {
        echo "bad";


    }
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>File Name</th>
                    <th>Serial Number</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Remarks</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <?php while ($row[image])?>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>" height="100" width="100"></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['file'] ?></td>
                    <th><?php echo $row['serialNumber'] ?></th>
                    <td><select name="status">
                            <option value="In use">In use</option>
                            <option value=Deleted>Deleted</option>

                    </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="remarks" /></td>

                </tr>

                </tbody>

</table>
<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" name="btn-update">Update</button>
</form>
```

class.user.php

```
public function updateBike($status,$remarks,$userID)
    {
        try
        {

//          echo $status;
//          echo$remarks;
//          echo$userID;
//          echo "UPDATE bike_tbl SET status=$status,remarks=$remarks WHERE userID=$userID:";


        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE bike_tbl SET status=:status,remarks=:remarks WHERE userID=:userID");

        $stmt->bindparam(":status",$status);
        $stmt->bindparam(":remarks",$remarks);
        $stmt->bindparam(":userID",$userID);

            $stmt->execute();

            return $stmt;
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: it appears as though you only have one `file` on the `bike_tbl`, so if that's the single image you're talking about, then you'll want to create another table with a one-to-many relationship from `bike_tbl`-to-`file_pics_tbl`

Comment: if user have 1 image and it show 1 image only . If user have 3 image my table should repeat for 3 images

Comment: You want to display all the images of the user in table right?

Comment: yes display all images that the user has uploaded. i only can display 1 image cant display the 2nd image

Comment: First explain me, in one column of table, how you store multiple images?

Comment: Better to use a separate table for images,